# Apply frame level crop for videos in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Would it be possible to specify crop for each frame in ffmpeg.

Example:

```
Frame 1 : crop=100:100:12:34
Frame 2 : crop=100:100:22:54
Frame 3 : crop=100:100:32:74
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the crop window size doesn't change and only x and y vary, this can be done directly inside the crop filter.

`crop=w=100:h=100:x='eq(n,0)*12+eq(n,1)*22+eq(n,2)*32':y='eq(n,0)*34+eq(n,1)*54+eq(n,2)*74'`

`n` is the frame number starting from 0.

Basic formula is `eq(n,X)*VALUE_FOR_FRAME_X+eq(n,Y)*VALUE_FOR_FRAME_Y+...`

Comment: This is perfect. Will there be any limitation on how big the command can be? Assume we have a video of 1 hr of 30 fps video, 3600*30= 108000 frames. That would be 1000's of lines of command.

Comment: That depends on your shell. You can use `-filter_script` to read the filtering arguments from a file.

Comment: great i will try that out.

Comment: I have tried below "ffmpeg -i VIDEO_20200518_085848.mp4 -filter:v -filter_script:filter.txt -c:a copy  out.mp4" but getting error [AVFilterGraph @ 02ae11c0] No such filter: '-filter_script:filter.txt'
Error opening filters! Any idea about this ?

Comment: Remove `-filter:v`

Comment: Error reads: [mp4 @ 000001f677891ec0] Invalid stream specifier: filter.txt.

Comment: Add -report and rerun command. Share report.

Answer (score 0):

How Can I do that
Replace x, y with my own defined array

Example:

Frame 1 : crop=100:100:x[1]:y[1]
Frame 2 : crop=100:100:x[2]:y[2]
Frame 3 : crop=100:100:x[3]:y[3]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).